# EDITING RHS VALUE WITHIN MULTIPLE SOLVES IN PYOMO

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to switch Gams to pyomo and I'm unexperienced in pyomo. I have a basic model to demonstrate my problem. I want to change right hand side value of some constraints between repeated solves. I dont want to add new constraints because in this case I gonna need to activate and deactivate constraints in loops. I try to change model.A1 by assigning a new value but in constraint4 it keeps 0.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd

obj_func_coef=pd.read_excel('veriler.xlsx',sheet_name='Goals')
cons_coef=pd.read_excel('veriler.xlsx',sheet_name='Cons')

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var(range(len(obj_func_coef)),bounds=(0,None), domain=Integers)
x=model.x
model.A1=pyo.Param(mutable=True, initialize=0)
model.A2=pyo.Param(mutable=True, initialize=0)  

def constraint1(model):
    return sum([cons_coef.C1[i]*x[i] for i in cons_coef.ID]) >= 15
def constraint2(model):
    return sum([cons_coef.C2[i]*x[i] for i in cons_coef.ID]) <= 14
def constraint3(model):
    return sum([cons_coef.C3[i]*x[i] for i in cons_coef.ID]) <= 20  
def constraint4(model):
     return sum([x[i]*obj_func_coef.Goal3[i] for i in obj_func_coef.ID])>=model.A1  
def constraint5(model):
    return sum([x[i]*obj_func_coef.Goal2[i] for i in obj_func_coef.ID])>=model.A2

def objective1(model):
    G1=sum([x[i]*obj_func_coef.Goal1[i] for i in obj_func_coef.ID])
    return G1

def objective2(model):
    G2=sum([x[i]*obj_func_coef.Goal2[i] for i in obj_func_coef.ID])
    return G2

opt=SolverFactory('gurobi')
opt.options['MIPgap']=0.0000000
G1=sum([x[i]*obj_func_coef.Goal1[i] for i in obj_func_coef.ID])
G2=sum([x[i]*obj_func_coef.Goal2[i] for i in obj_func_coef.ID])

#------------------------------------------------------------
model.con1 = Constraint(rule=constraint1)
model.con2 = Constraint(rule=constraint2)
model.con3 = Constraint(rule=constraint3)
model.con4 = Constraint(expr=constraint4)
model.con5 = Constraint(rule=constraint5)

#---------------------------------------------------------------
model.obj1=pyo.Objective(rule=objective1, sense= pyo.maximize)
opt.solve(model)
print('---1---', pyo.value(G1), pyo.value(G2))
model.A1=pyo.value(G1)
model.obj1.deactivate()
model.obj2=pyo.Objective(rule=objective2, sense= pyo.maximize)  
opt.solve(model)     
print('----1-2----',pyo.value(G1),pyo.value(G2))
model.A2=pyo.value(G2)
```

run gives

> > > ---1--- 20.0 8.0
> > > ----1-2---- 15.0 11.0

but it should give

> > > ---1--- 20.0 8.0
> > > ----1-2---- 20.0 10.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit confusing and missing some values to make it reproducible.

You can just change the value of mutable parameter(s) and re-solve, or activate/deactivate objectives as you are attempting to do.

also, in 99% of cases for simple models, all you need to do is import the pyomo environment.  Years ago it was refactored to contain almost everything you need for basic models.

Here is an example of changing the RHS of an indexed constraint:

#### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m =  pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=[1, 2])

m.x = pyo.Var(m.S)

m.limit = pyo.Param(m.S, default=5, mutable=True)

# constrain x
def limit_x(m, s):
    return m.x[s] <= m.limit[s]
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(m.S, rule=limit_x)

# OBJ
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(m.x[s] for s in m.S), sense=pyo.maximize)


# solve
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
res = solver.solve(m)

print(res)  # obj value = 10

# change the RHS of the constraint
m.limit[1] = 2
m.limit[2] = 4

res = solver.solve(m)

print(res)  # obj value = 6
```